# Add an easy to manage news section to ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET based web app, and I want to add an update/news section to the portal. I don't want to add this through a table that reads data from the database, but use some other way that easily allows me to publish this news content/website updates on the portal.

I'm looking at using blogengine.net to publish the content for now. But I'm open to something simpler as an ASP.NET control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with @ShoaibShaikh - you could define a simple xml file format (perhaps take a look at the RSS formats) and, in your control, bind a repeater to it.